# i am un able to get the script to print the output dynamicaly

Tags: python, security, scapy, packet-sniffers

when running the following script nothing gets printed but when i press ctrl+c and end the task the complete output is printed. i want to make it in a way that each line of list is dynamicaly printed as the script is running itself
the function i am trying to  run is...
`

```
`def passive_scan(interface):
    result=[]
    ip=[]
    packets = []
    mode="p"
    sniff(iface="eth0", prn=filter_packets(packets),timeout= 10000)
    for p in packets:
        if p[0]["ARP"].op==2:
            src_mac=p[0]["ARP"].hwsrc
            src_ip=p[0]["ARP"].psrc
            ip.append(src_ip)
            dict={"mac":src_mac,"ip":src_ip}
            result.append(dict)
    for client in result:
        client["count"]=countOf(ip,client["ip"])
    print_result(result,mode)`
```

`
the output printing function i am using is .....

````
```
`print("Interface: "+interface+"\t\tMode: Passive\t\t\tFound "+str(len(list))+" hosts")        
print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("MAC\t\t\t\tIP\t\t\tHost Activity")
print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
for client in list:
    print(client["mac"] + "\t\t" + client["ip"]+"\t\t"+str(client["count"]))`
```

```
`


i was able to properly format the output but to get that to print i have to end the task than only it prints



the required output should look like..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g14d.png)
````

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior of `sniff()` which is a blocking function.

"The `sniff()` function listens for an infinite period of time until the user interrupts."

You should use the `AsyncSniffer` : https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#asynchronous-sniffing